# Add comment to an ARFF file

Tags: java, comments, weka, arff

this is my first question in this forum.... 
I'm making adata-mining application in java with the WEKA API.
I make first a pre-processing stage and when I save the ARFF file i would like to add a couple of lines (as comments) specifing the preprocessing task that i have done to the file...
the problem is that i don't know how to add comments to an ARFF file from the java WEKA API.
To save the file i use the class ArffSaver like this...

```
    try {
        ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
        saver.setInstances(dataPost);
        saver.setFile(arffFile);
        saver.writeBatch();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Preprocesamiento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
```

I would be really greatfull if someone could give some idea...
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should AVOID writting comments on an .arff file, even more when writting it from Java. These files are very "parser-sensitive". The Weka API to create these files is restrictive for this particular reason.

Even though, you can always add your comments manually with the **%** symbol. This said, I wouldn't recommend you writting anything more than instances, attributes and values into an .arff file. ;-)

Comment: Is there any reason not to add comments? The specification clearly allows it. And I think that, as a form of provenance in data mining and data science, it is *really* important to retain information about how a data set was created. And comments that describe the preprocessing steps are the least that one could do in this case.

Comment: @Marco13 I don't really know anything about the updates on Weka, and Arff files. I replied to this 5 years ago. If you read carefully you'll see: "The Weka API to create these files is restrictive for this particular reason." In that time there were TONS of problems reading from Arff files with comments on them. Maybe coding issues, etc.. Everyone knows comments are ESSENTIAL, but in this case you could have a nicely commented but unreadable dataset. On that time I preferred having a separate TXT with the comments on them.

Comment: Fair enough: An ARFF file that is "unreadable" is useless in any case. But the built-in ARFF-reader must be (and as far as I can tell **is**) aware of the `%` comments, so everything should be fine here.

Comment: Just had to put some background on my reply ; ). Your position is correct, thou. They should've get ridden of any problems by now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to **not** write comments into the header of an ARFF file. The [specification](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) clearly says:

> Lines that begin with a % are comments.

So while it is technically valid, it can be difficult if you want to use the `ArffSaver#setFile` method. This method does a lot of (convenient, but somewhat arbitrary and unspecified) work internally, until it finally calls

```
setDestination(new FileOutputStream(m_outputFile));
```

If this is not required, the easiest option is to write directly to an `OutputStream`, which then can simply be set as the destination for the `ArffSaver`. This can be wrapped in a small helper method, for example, like this:

```
static void writeArff(
    Instances instances, 
    List<String> commentLines, 
    OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
{
    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
    saver.setInstances(instances);
    if (commentLines != null && !commentLines.isEmpty())
    {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
        for (String commentLine : commentLines)
        {
            bw.write("% " + commentLine + "\n");
        }
        bw.write("\n");
        bw.flush();
    }
    saver.setDestination(outputStream);
    saver.writeBatch();
}
```

When calling it like this

```
 List<String> comments = Arrays.asList("A comment", "Another one");
writeArff(instances, comments, outputStream);
```

then the given comments will be inserted at the top of the ARFF file.